# Browser.execute is returning Undefined for all

Tags: javascript, selenium, nightwatch.js

I am fetching few values from the Web Page using custom javascript in Nightwatch.

```
browser.execute(function () {
    priceValues = {
        total: document.querySelectorAll('someLocator').innerText,
        individualPrice: document.querySelectorAll('someLocator').innerText,
        discount: document.querySelectorAll('someLocator').innerText,
    };
    return priceValues;
}, [], function (result) {
    totalPrice = result.value.total;
    individual = result.value.individualPrice;
    discountPrice = result.value.discount;
});
```

The problem I am facing is that for some tests I don't have the **discount** so I am getting undefined there, but due to this the other two **total** and **individualprice** whose values are present are also getting undefined. It would be great if someone could point out where am I doing wrong.

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll()` return a NodeList which does not has property: `innerText`. So the `total`, `individualPrice` and `discount` should are always `undefined` in any situation, not the `discount` only is `undefined` in some situation.

Comment: @yong But when I comment out **discount** everything works fine, the other two returns the expected values.

Comment: I always get `undefined` when execute following script `console.log(document.querySelectorAll('body').innerText)` in my Chrome's DevTool's Console

Comment: @yong But it works for me.

Comment: @yong I was able to achieve what I was looking for, turns out the problem was the innerText as mentioned by you, so when I separated it from priceValues and its working :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do it with the below block of code:

```
browser.execute(function () {
    priceValues = {
        total: document.querySelectorAll('someLocator').innerText,
        individualPrice: document.querySelectorAll('someLocator').innerText,
    };
    var discount = document.querySelectorAll('someLocator'),

    if (discount && discount.innerText) {
        priceValues.discount = discount.innerText;
    }
    return priceValues;
}, [], function (result) {
    totalPrice = result.value.total;
    individual = result.value.individualPrice;
    discountPrice = result.value.discount;
});
```